# How to set system properties while calling testng xml from the shell script

Tags: java, shell, testng

My requirement is as below.

i have a shell script, which is going to run the testng.xml(it runs the testng scripts). So i have to set the system properties while calling testng.xml which intern calls the testng script(system properties are being used by these testng java files)

Please can any one help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you are starting TestNG in the Java-ecosystem, you are always free to use system properties after the -D option, like this:

```
java -Dprop.key="property value" appToRun
```

You can then access those properties in the common way...

```
System.getProperty("prop.key");
```